# Why does Firebase Realtime Database User ID not match with the Firebase Authentication UID after signing up a user?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase and am currently working on creating a social media-esque platform to help improve my understanding of both React Native as well as Firebase. I am currently trying to query a value from my User collection in Real Time Database. I am unable to do so due to there being a mismatch between the newly created user/logged in user and the correlated data of said user in their UIDs.

[image: Real Time Database View of Data]

[image: Firebase Authentication of same User]

The UIDs between both of these users are not the same despite being created at the same time during sign up and I have been having a hard time trying to understand why. Below is how I set up creating a user and storing the needed information into the DB.

```
const handleSignup = () => {
    if (!email) {
      alert("Please enter your email address");
      return;
    }

    if (!password) {
      alert("Please enter a password");
      return;
    }

    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((userCredentials) => {
        const user = userCredentials.user;
        console.log("Registered with:", user.email);
        navigation.replace("Tabs");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const createUser = () => {
    const userRef = firebase.database().ref("User");
    const userData = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      userName: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
    };
    userRef.push(userData);
  };

  const writeUserData = (
    fname,
    lname,
    email,
    password,
    username,
    phoneNumber
  ) => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("User/")
      .push({
        email,
        fname,
        lname,
        password,
        username,
        phoneNumber,
      })
      .then((data) => {
        //success callback
        console.log("data ", data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        //error callback
        console.log("error ", error);
      });
  };

  const handleSignupAndCreateUser = () => {
    handleSignup();
    createUser();
    writeUserData(fname, lname, email, password, username, phoneNumber);
  };
```

I tried to set the value of a variable to be equal to the user.uid and then set the path when pushing the data but was met with the error of: "Type Error: userID is read only". Any ideas as to why this would be the case with the UIDs between the different services?

Answer (score 0):

```
 FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 String userId     = user.getUid();
```

Try this because the child id and the user id are in different paths. With this, you get the current user id and can continue when you push to the database with this userid.